# In python, is there a way to automatically log information any time you create a variable?

Tags: python, logging

Not sure if this makes sense at all, but here's an example:

Let's say I have a script.  In this script, I create a list

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

Maybe I just don't have the technical vocabulary to find what I'm looking for, but is there any way I could set some logging up so that any time I created a variable I could store information in a log file?  Given the above example, maybe I'd want to see how many elements are in the list?

I understand that I could simply write a function and call that over and over again, but let's say I might want to know information about a ton of different data types, not just lists.  It wouldn't be clean to call a function repeatedly.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Could you tell us what the broader picture of this is, and _why_?

Comment: @Felipe  That's fair.  Well, it is for my job.  Basically, I'd like to automate some QA features so that I don't have to constantly type out code to make sure that my code isn't calculating things incorrectly.

Comment: I think this would be possible if you made a custom subclass of dictionary, and then created all your variables as entries inside the dictionary.  I don't know how it would be possible with plain free-standing variables as you gave in the example.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do unit tests instead of logging every variable.

Comment: Klaus said it best. You likely want to look into testing your code with either [unitest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) or [PyTest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

this is hackery but what the heck

```
class _LoggeryType(type):
     def __setattr__(cls,attr,value):
         print("SET VAR: {0} = {1}".format(attr,value))
         globals().update({attr:value})

# Python3
class Loggery(metaclass=_LoggeryType):
      pass

# python2
class Loggery:
    __metaclass__=_LoggeryType



Loggery.x = 5
print("OK set X={0}".format(x))
```

note i wouldn't really recommend using this

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use the powerful `sys.settrace`. I've written up a small (but somewhat incomplete) example:

tracer.py:

```
import inspect
import sys
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('tracing-logger')

FILES_TO_TRACE = [os.path.basename(__file__), 'tracee.py']
print(FILES_TO_TRACE)

def new_var(name, value, context):
    logger.debug(f"New {context} variable called {name} = {value}")
    # do some analysis here, for example
    if type(value) == list:
        logger.debug(f"\tNumber of elements: {len(value)}")

def changed_var(name, value, context):
    logger.debug(f"{context} variable called {name} of was changed to: {value}")

def make_tracing_func():
    current_locals = {}
    current_globals = {}
    first_line_executed = False

    def tracing_func(frame, event, arg):
        nonlocal first_line_executed

        frame_info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
        filename = os.path.basename(frame_info.filename)
        line_num = frame_info.lineno

        if event == 'line':
            # check for difference with locals
            for var_name in frame.f_code.co_varnames:
                if var_name in frame.f_locals:
                    var_value = frame.f_locals[var_name]
                    if var_name not in current_locals:
                        current_locals[var_name] = var_value
                        new_var(var_name, var_value, 'local')
                    elif current_locals[var_name] != var_value:
                        current_locals[var_name] = var_value
                        changed_var(var_name, var_value, 'local')

            for var_name, var_value in frame.f_globals.items():
                if var_name not in current_globals:
                    current_globals[var_name] = var_value
                    if first_line_executed:
                        new_var(var_name, var_value, 'global')

                elif current_globals[var_name] != var_value:
                    current_globals[var_name] = var_value
                    changed_var(var_name, var_value, 'global')

            first_line_executed = True
            return tracing_func

        elif event == 'call':
            if os.path.basename(filename) in FILES_TO_TRACE:
                return make_tracing_func()
        return None

    return tracing_func


sys.settrace(make_tracing_func())
import tracee
```

tracee.py

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = 3
print("tracee: I have a list!", my_list)
c = a + sum(my_list)
print("tracee: A number:", c)
c = 12
print("tracee: I changed it:", c)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:tracing-logger:New global variable called my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
DEBUG:tracing-logger:   Number of elements: 4
DEBUG:tracing-logger:New global variable called a = 3
tracee: I have a list! [1, 2, 3, 4]
DEBUG:tracing-logger:New global variable called c = 13
tracee: A number: 13
DEBUG:tracing-logger:global variable called c was changed to: 12
tracee: I changed it: 12
```

There are some additional cases you may want to handle (duplicated changes to globals due to function calls, closure variables, etc.). You can also use `linecache` to find the contents of the lines, or use the `line_num` variable in the logging.

Comment: Could you explain what's going on here? What's the scope of this? It looks like declaring or assigning to any global variable triggers a print statement?